# How to use place api in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-places-api

When I try to use the google place API in flutter using a normal key without any restriction It's saying

```
{"error_message":"You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started","predictions":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

and billing is already enabled and When I restrict the API for android mobile it shows IP related error

**Solution**

The problem is in the billing account. My existing billing account was for the google cloud platform not for the google map platform so while creating a billing account be careful about the purpose otherwise it won't work.

Comment: where did you get the normal key?

Comment: Normal key I mean key without any restriction

Answer (score 0):

Before you start using the Places API, you need a project with a billing account and the Places API enabled. To learn more, see Set up in Cloud Console.

Creating API keys
The API key is a unique identifier that authenticates requests associated with your project for usage and billing purposes. You must have at least one API key associated with your project.

To create an API key:

Go to the APIs & Services > Credentials page.

Go to the Credentials page

On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key.
The API key created dialog displays your newly created API key.
Click Close.
The new API key is listed on the Credentials page under API keys.
(Remember to restrict the API key before using it in production.)
Restricting API keys
Restricting API Keys adds security to your application by ensuring only authorized requests are made with your API Key. We strongly recommend that you follow the instructions to set restrictions for your API Keys. For more information, see API Key best practices.

To restrict an API key:

Go to the APIs & Services > Credentials page.

Go to the Credentials page

Select the API key that you want to set a restriction on. The API key property page appears.
Under Key restrictions, set the following restrictions:
Application restrictions:
To accept requests from the list of web server IP addresses that you supply, select IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) from the list of Application restrictions.
Specify one IPv4 or IPv6 address or a subnet using CIDR notation (e.g. 192.168.0.0/22). If you need to enter another entry, a new box appears after you complete adding the previous entry.
API restrictions:
Click Restrict key.
Select Places API from Select APIs dropdown. If the Places API is not listed, you need to enable it.
To finalize your changes, click Save.
Adding the API key to your request
You must include an API key with every Places API request. In the following example, replace YOUR_API_KEY with your API key.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&key=YOUR_API_KEY
HTTPS is required for requests that use an API key, and recommended for requests that use a client ID. HTTPS is also required for applications that include sensitive user data - such as a user's location - in requests.

Official doc
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key